# SES integration in Magento with code

Tags: magento, integration, amazon-ses

Please help me to integrate ses in magento as i have tried below method for sending email.But not getting any of the email in my inbox or spam.sendEmail()is not sending email.I have tried both for localhost and on server neither of them sending an email.

```
    $config = array('auth' => 'login',
           'username' => '***************',
           'port'=>587,
           'SMTP'=>true,// SMTP
            'SMTPAuth'   => true,  // SMTP authentication
            'Mailer' => "smtp",
           'enable_starttls_auto' => true,
           'host'=>"email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
           'password' => '**************************');

    ini_set('SMTP', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'));
    ini_set('smtp_port', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'));
    $ses = new SimpleEmailService($config);
    $m = new SimpleEmailServiceMessage();
    $m->addTo('xyz.test@gmail.com');
    $m->setFrom('xyz.test@gmail.com');
    $m->setSubject('You have got Email!');
    $m->setMessageFromString('Your message');
   if($ses->sendEmail($m)){
    echo "done";die;
   }
```

One of the try given me this error:-
stdClass Object ( [error] => Array ( [curl] => 1 [code] => 60 [message] => SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate [resource] => ) )